# Google's spreadsheets: Clear columns programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have some items recorded

[image: My spreadsheet]

How to programmatically clear all the lines, starting from the second line, i mean **except** from the bold titles (NAME,BARCODE,QUANTITY,PRICE)?

This is my goal

[image]

And this is what i have done. How to continue?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":D"+num+"");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

player019, try this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
range = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
range.clearContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`getMaxRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) and [`getMaxColumns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxColumns()) to get the last row and col. So, you may want to try:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var startRow = 2;
var startCol = 1;
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
sheet.setActiveRange(range);
range.clearContent();
```